# Tapping in garage door opener outlet for ring flood light/gfci?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci, garage

Ok so really I have a 2 part question. The 20 amp garage circuit breaker says it’s gfi protected on my panel and has one gfi outlet on my garage wall. I tested this by tripping a normal wall outlet in my garage with a tester. All of the outlets were tripped except for the outlet that is plugged into my garage door opener which is on the ceiling. They are both on the same 20 amp breaker but the roof receptacle that my garage opener is plugged into did not trip. I know this to be true because when I go to turn off power in the garage at the panel. The outlets on the wall and the one on the roof does not work, but the only outlet that can be tripped by my tester is all but the roof receptacle. Does this mean that it’s not technically protected by GFI (2003 home)?

Second half of this question. I have connected to the receptacle on the roof that my garage opener is plugged into, a light bulb (12/2). This is properly placed into a junction box and what tapped into via wire nuts into the roof receptacle.

Am I able to then connect a Ring flood light using 12/2 and 3 way wago wire levels to tap into this and run a line for this ring flood lamp through the attic?

This is a lot to explain so feel free to ask for clarification and thank you

Comment: since it is on the ceiling it probably does not need GFCI

Comment: @Ruskes Yes and no. Since it is on the ceiling *it didn't need protection in 2003*. It *might* need it now, not sure, but that would be for a new circuit. So *probably* doesn't need GFCI, but a little research would be needed to know for sure.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact so you agree with me, or do not agree with me, or maybe something else

Comment: I am saying that in 2003 it didn't need GFCI. But it *might* need GFCI in 2023, depending on local code adoption. If it does need GFCI then the existing circuit would not be affected - it is grandfathered. But adding something new would trigger the requirement. If it is then required, the actual GFCI could not be placed in the ceiling because it has to be accessible, but there are a number of ways of handling that.

Comment: Since the flood light is outside it should be protected by GFCI

Comment: OP, when you say "roof" do you really mean "ceiling?"

Comment: Please [edit] this into two distinct questions as the only thing they have in common is the receptacle on ceiling. As it stands, this is too broad (take the [tour]) and will likely be closed as "needing more focus". Additionally, it also needs more detail on each of the situations. With the breaker _OFF_ open up several of the receptacles in question and get clear, focused pics of the wiring to help us help you.

Comment: @Ruskes - do you have a code reference for outdoor lighting (not receptacle) needing GFCI protection? I can't find that, but can easily have missed something.

Answer (score 1):

The NEC requirements for GFCI protection changes almost every cycle. Work done in 2003 needed to be done according to the Code as locally adopted with local amendments at that time. Work done now must be done per currently adopted Code.

GFCI requirements apply to receptacles. As of 2023 the NEC says:

> 210.8(A) Dwelling Units. All 125-volt through 250-volt receptacles installed in the locations specified in 210.8(A)(1) through (A)⁠(11)
> and supplied by single-phase branch circuits rated 150 volts or less
> to ground shall have ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection for
> personnel.
>
> (1) Bathrooms
>
> (2) Garages and also accessory buildings that have a floor located at
> or below grade level not intended as habitable rooms and limited to
> storage areas, work areas, and areas of similar use.

The 2002 NEC didn't include receptacles above 125v, and there was an exception that exempted receptacles that were not readily accessible. Making things more difficult the current Code requires the reset for GFCI receptacles be **Readily Accessible**:

> Capable of being reached quickly for operation, renewal, or
> inspections without requiring those to whom ready access is requisite
> to actions such as to use tools, to climb over or remove obstacles, or
> to resort to portable ladders, and so forth

So if you use three hole wago style connectors to tap off that existing unprotected ceiling mounted receptacle to feed a new receptacle the new receptacle needs to be protected. If the location you mount the new receptacle is not Readily Accessible then you will need to first feed a receptacle location that is Readily Accessible, then feed the inaccessible receptacle from the load terminals of the protected receptacle or the whole circuit needs to be protected by a GFCI breaker.

Lights are allowed on GFCI circuits, but are not required to be protected.